# Reducing AWS CloudWatch agent CPU usage

Tags: performance, amazon-cloudwatch, cpu-usage

We have the CloudWatch agent installed on one EC2 instance and even with 4 cores the task takes up 24% of total CPU time. Is there a way to configure this to be less of a CPU strain? Perhaps to drop the sample rate or have it idle for periods?

While the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AgentReference.html) mentioned a cron job, I see nowhere information on how to set up a scheduled task to have the agent work intermittently. For example, it would be nice to have it fired up once every 5 minutes, send results to the cloud, then shutdown - perhaps with a powershell task.

Answer (score 1):

I reduced CPU usage significantly by removing use of the ** super asterisk.

Also, regarding collection interval, there is a setting in the config file to set collection interval (default is 60 seconds)

```
"metrics_collection_interval": 60
```

[AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Agent-Configuration-File-Details.html)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to limit the CPU usage from 15-20% to 0-0.2% by:

1. Removing old logs from the folder - There were around 500MB of logs and the agent was processing everything
2. Updating to the latest version